# Does XSS always require a server-side vulnerability to work?

Tags: xss

Apologies if this turns out to be a stupid question...  It's in the context of an idealised, unattainable hypothetical to help me understand the heart of an XSS attack:

If a run-of-the-mill, does-nothing-adventurous non-malicious *but unsecured* HTML/CSS/JS script client-side is exchanging JSON data (no files/filesystem involved) to/from a *completely bullet-proof* PHP/MySQL script server-side, is XSS possible?

Or are *all* XSS attacks *always* based on the ability to access/alter/store *something* server-side?

I'm just trying to get my head around where the "edges" are.  I have read dozens of articles/posts on XSS over the past few days, but if the answer is in any of them, I've not understood it. :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start with the wiki entry for a good overview https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, XSS is about being able to run javascript in a user's context, supplied via application inputs. This means doing it via say developer console does not count, the user actively has to open the console and do things that he would not normally do - that is not a valid attack vector in most cases. However, all application inputs (inputs on the UI, the url bar, request headers and so on) are potential ways for injecting javascript.

In case of reflected or stored xss, the request is sent to the server, and the response contains javascript from the request in a way that it gets run on the client. So those need a server.

However, in case of DOM xss, it can all be on the client, in vulnerable javascript code.

Consider an example where the UI has an input field, and when the user clicks a button ("send"), whatever he entered gets added to some kind of a log ("a chat window" for example), by javascript on the client. If the user enters `<script>alert(1)</script>`, it might get appended as html to the log area, thus being executed as javascript, without ever being sent to a server. This would be an example of DOM xss, and the fix is obviously to append it as a text node, instead of html.

This is usually rated lower risk, because in many cases a remote attacker has limited opportunity to actually exploit this against an unsuspecting user. But it's still a vulnerability (for example an attacker might get a user to copy-paste something into a field and so on).

Also a typical exploitable case of this is when javascript reads and adds to the DOM a part of the url, which can actually be supplied by a remote attacker (in the form of a link sent to a victim user).